# Dropmenu won't appear when i hover it css html

Tags: html, css, frontend

Hello so i have a issue with my dropmenu when i hover it nothing happen can please someone tell what wrong i try to change visibility hidden by display none/block when i hover but nothing change.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: "Merriweather", serif;
}

nav {
  width: 100%;
  height: 80px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 20px;
}

.logo {
  font-size: 30px;
}

.navitems {
  display: flex;
  list-style: none;
  gap: 50px;
  font-size: 20px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.drophover {
  position: relative;
}

.dropmenu {
  position: absolute;
  top: 80px;
  list-style: none;
  line-height: 60px;
  text-align: left;
  box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.06) 0px 2px 4px 0px inset;
  padding: 10px;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 200ms ease-in-out;
}

.drophover:hover.dropmenu {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <nav>
    <h1 class="logo">Morroco.</h1>
    <ul class="navitems">
      <li class="drophover">Découvrir le Maroc</li>
      <ul class="dropmenu">
        <li>Histoire & Géographie</li>
        <li>Art & Culture</li>
        <li>Téchnologie</li>
      </ul>
      <li>Destinations</li>
      <li>Infos Pratique</li>
      <li>Nous Contacter</li>
    </ul>
    <i><img src="/img/menu_FILL0_wght400_GRAD0_opsz48.svg" alt="" /></i>
  </nav>
</header>
```

I try to change opacity and visibility by display none and display block when i hover but nothing change

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to select your `dropmenu` using the sibling selector:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: "Merriweather", serif;
}

nav {
  width: 100%;
  height: 80px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 20px;
}

.logo {
  font-size: 30px;
}

.navitems {
  display: flex;
  list-style: none;
  gap: 50px;
  font-size: 20px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.drophover {
  position: relative;
}

.dropmenu {
  position: absolute;
  top: 80px;
  list-style: none;
  line-height: 60px;
  text-align: left;
  box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.06) 0px 2px 4px 0px inset;
  padding: 10px;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: 200ms ease-in-out;
}

/*  CSS sibling selector */
.drophover:hover + .dropmenu {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <title>Document</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/maroc.css" />
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com" />
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin />
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Merriweather:ital,wght@0,300;0,400;0,700;0,900;1,300;1,400;1,700;1,900&display=swap" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <nav>
      <h1 class="logo">Morroco.</h1>
      <ul class="navitems">
        <li class="drophover">Découvrir le Maroc</li>
        <ul class="dropmenu">
          <li>Histoire & Géographie</li>
          <li>Art & Culture</li>
          <li>Téchnologie</li>
        </ul>
        <li>Destinations</li>
        <li>Infos Pratique</li>
        <li>Nous Contacter</li>
      </ul>
      <i><img src="/img/menu_FILL0_wght400_GRAD0_opsz48.svg" alt="" /></i>
    </nav>
  </header>
  <main></main>
  <footer></footer>
</body>

</html>
```